# return parent object with filtered child array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, underscore.js, nested-lists

Sample Data:

```
{
    "QuestionId": 2,
    "QuestionName": "Question2",
    "QuestionTypeId": 2,
    "QuestionTypeName": "CheckBoxList",
    "Choices": [{
            "ChoiceId": 7,
            "ChoiceName": "Choice1",
            "Answer": "7"
        },
        {
            "ChoiceId": 8,
            "ChoiceName": "Choice2",
            "Answer": ""
        },
        {
            "ChoiceId": 9,
            "ChoiceName": "Choice3",
            "Answer": ""
        },
        {
            "ChoiceId": 10,
            "ChoiceName": "Choice4",
            "Answer": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on the sample data, How can this be returned with filtered Choices maintaining the same structure using Underscore or any better javascript approach? The Choice is filtered based on Choice.Answer. The answer must have a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter out choices with blank answers, use `Array.filter` - I also assume your above data structure is within an array (an array of questions)

```
//Loop over each question
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    //For each question, filter the "Choices" array to not include empty Answers
    questions[i].Choices = questions[i].Choices.filter(function(choice) {
        return choice.Answer != ""
    })
}
```

Comment: Your solution is now part of my solution. Thank you.